# Connected to an Unsigned HTTPs site using Java Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, ssl-certificate

I am trying setup a Java program to connect to a website of my own that is using SSL. I have it fully working for a standard HTTP site, but not for HTTPs. My issue is that I don't have my certificate signed.

How can I have java ignore the fact that it isn't signed and let me connect anyways? I get this error when I try to connect:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at util.Watchlist.getWatchListWebsiteReaderSSL(Watchlist.java:51)
    at util.Watchlist.updateWLDP(Watchlist.java:64)
    at util.Watchlist.getWLDP(Watchlist.java:24)
    at commands.devices.cpt.WldpMessage.run(WldpMessage.java:52)
    at cli.Parser.Parse(Parser.java:74)
    at fromUI.UISocketReader.run(UISocketReader.java:54)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(Unknown Source)
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(Unknown Source)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(Unknown Source)
    ... 25 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create a TrustManager that accepts unsigned certificates and associate that with the SSLContext used for HTTPS connections. There is a simple example at http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.net.ssl/trustall.html

```
// Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[]{
  new X509TrustManager() {
    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
    }
    public void checkClientTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
    public void checkServerTrusted(
        java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {}
  }
};

// Install the all-trusting trust manager
try {
  SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
  sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
  HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
} catch (Exception e) {
}

// Now you can access an https URL without having the certificate in the 
// truststore
try {
  URL url = new URL("https://hostname/index.html");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
}
```

Please be aware that the linked example does no verification whatsoever on the server's SSL certificate thus you won't be able to fully trust the identity of the website you connect to.

Comment: Well this got me 1 step further. I'm now getting a "Received fatal alert: bad_record_mac". I think it may have to do with the SSL version on the sever. If you happen to know please let me know. Your help has been great though!

Comment: That TrustManager doesn't comply with its specification. The technique of accepting all certificates should never be used in production code as it fundamentally breaks SSL security. See the discussion in RFC 2246.

Comment: @EJP I am just working on a proof of concept so weakening SSL is fine. In production SSL will be signed.